# Batch script that will get files name and rename those files in Linux

Tags: batch-file

I was trying to create a batch script that will get all the files (using `ls` command) and append those files in a text file. After that, it will look for each filename available in text file and check if those file names have `.abc.ms` at the end of the file name. If `.abc.ms` is available, then it will do nothing; if it is not available, then it will rename them (on Linux server using `mv`) with *"file name"*`.abc.ms` .
 Below is my code and I am unable to rename those files:

```
E:\plink -i E:\abc.ppk user@linuxserver ls /xyz/vc/dt/bbb/toy/ >> %filetemp%
FOR /f %%F IN (%filetemp%) DO (
    echo %%F >>C:\temp1.txt
    ::if "*lock.processed"=="%%F"
    find /i "lock.processed" C:\GE_RESTRICTED\RITM\NewTask\temp1.txt
    if not %errorlevel%==0 (
    E:\plink -i E:\abc.ppk user@linuxserver mv %%F %%F.lock.processed
    )
)
```

...where `%filetemp%` is a text file used to store all the names from linux server.

Comment: Are you sure that is Linux? This is MS-DOS code

Comment: @Valijon: It's both, as he is SSHing to a linux box from a batch script. @Prax: You mention the suffix `.abc.ms` in your question, but it doesn't appear in your code - shouldn't that be `.lock.processed`?

Comment: @zb226 yes...It is .loc.processed

Answer (score 0):

If you open an SSH shell (which is effectively what you are doing when using `plink.exe`), you start off in the home directory of the user you are connecting with, probably something like `/home/user`. Since the files you want to rename reside somewhere else (Looking at your `ls` command, the location is `/xyz/vc/dt/bbb/toy/`), I think you just need to prepend that full path to files you want to rename:

```
E:\plink -i E:\abc.ppk user@linuxserver ls /xyz/vc/dt/bbb/toy/ >> %filetemp%
FOR /f %%F IN (%filetemp%) DO (
    echo %%F >>C:\temp1.txt
    ::if "*lock.processed"=="%%F"
    find /i "lock.processed" C:\GE_RESTRICTED\RITM\NewTask\temp1.txt
    if not %errorlevel%==0 (
    E:\plink -i E:\abc.ppk user@linuxserver mv /xyz/vc/dt/bbb/toy/%%F /xyz/vc/dt/bbb/toy/%%F.lock.processed
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

following is the solution for my question:

```
pushd C:\JobTest\src
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d-h-s') do (
echo %%f >>C:\NewTask\temp.txt
)



FOR /f %%a IN (C:\NewTask\temp.txt) DO (
::set FileName=%%~nxa
if not "%%~xa"==".processed"  E:\plink -i E:\abc.ppk user@linuxserver mv /xyz/vc/dt/bbb/toy/%%~fa /xyz/vc/dt/bbb/toy/%%~nxa.processed

)
popd
```

Comment: So you are now using a local source to fetch the filenames? And a modified way to check for yet another suffix `.processed`? And you're prepending the full path as I suggested?